# How to plot a graph with separate scale reference lines?

Tags: pgfplots

I have searched through different plots generated by pgfplots and could not find my desired style as below:
I know how to hide axes, but would like to know does PGFplots have an option to automatically generate scale reference lines (seen at southeast of the image)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `after end axis/.code` to execute some drawing code after everything else is done, and the `axis direction cs:` to define lines in terms of axis units.

Here's a key called `scale reference` that draws a scale reference like the one you showed. You can customise the lengths of the bars using `scale reference x length`, the line style and position using `scale reference style`, and the labels using `scale reference x unit`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    plot coordinates/math parser=false,
    every axis/.append style={
        tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
        label style={font=\scriptsize}
    }
}

\pgfplotsset{
    scale reference style/.style={
        every scale reference/.append style={#1}
    },
    every scale reference/.style={
        shift={(rel axis cs:0,0)},
        thick
    },
    scale reference/x unit/.initial={},
    scale reference/y unit/.initial={},
    scale reference/x length/.initial=1,
    scale reference/y length/.initial=1,
    scale reference/.style={
        /pgfplots/scale reference/.cd,
        #1,
        /pgfplots/after end axis/.code={
            \draw [/pgfplots/every scale reference] (0,0) --
                ++(axis direction cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/x length},0)
                    node [/pgfplots/every tick label, pos=0.5, below] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/x length} \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/x unit}}
                -- ++(0,5pt);
            \draw [/pgfplots/every scale reference] (0,0) -- ++(axis direction cs:0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/y length}) node [/pgfplots/every tick label, pos=0.5, left, ] {\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/y length}\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/scale reference/y unit}} -- ++(5pt,0);
        }
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=0:pi,
    width=10cm, height=4cm,
    enlargelimits=false,
    hide axis,
    scale reference={
        x unit=secs,
        y unit=$\mu$V,
        x length=0.5,
        y length=50
    },
    scale reference style={shift={(rel axis cs:0,-0.1)}}
]
\addplot [samples=500] {50*sin(deg(x*20))*sin(deg(x*20/7*rnd/2))+rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake! Really helpful. How can I configure this code to automatically use the font setting defined for tick labels and axis labels for scale reference?

Comment: @M.Reza: Glad it helps! I've edited the code so the x and y tick label styles are now automatically used for the scale reference labels, and the syntax has been cleaned up a bit (you don't have to say `scale reference x unit` any more, you can just pass `x unit` to the `scale reference` key).

Comment: Thanks Jake for the update. I used the 
   `\pgfplotsset{
    compat=newest,
    plot coordinates/math parser=false,
    every axis/.append style={
           tick label style={font=\scriptsize}
           label style={font=\scriptsize}
    }'
To adjust the global fonts, however it seems not effective on the scale reference fonts.

Comment: @M.Reza: I've changed the code so the labels now respect the style set in `tick label style`.

Comment: A small add on to the answer, If you would like to rotate ylabel: change `node [/pgfplots/every tick label, pos=0.5, left, ]` to `node [/pgfplots/every tick label,rotate=90, pos=0.5, above]`